# Two equals or not two equals

Tags: google-apps-script, switch-statement

I am working with 5 options: O, R, 1, 2, 3.  My function here is trying to convert O and R to numeric equivalents while leaving the number values alone.I have tried this two ways and neither is working. This is the first way I tried it.  It does not change any values at all.

```
function Level2Number (Level) //changes level R and O to numbers 
{
  switch (Level)
  {
    case (Level == "R"):
      return 0
      break;

    case (Level == "O"):
      return .5
      break;

   default:
      return Level
      break;
   }
}
```

When I tried it this next way, it is doing what I want with the O and the R but i is placing the letter O in place of the 1, 2, and 3.

function Level2Number (Level) //changes level R and O to numbers for further calculation.//
{
  switch (Level)
                                                                         {
        case (Level = "R"):
          return 0
          break;

```
    case (Level = "O"):
      return .5
      break;

    default:
      return Level
      break;
   }
}
```

I am not sure how to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because logical expressions (as indicated by the parentheses) evaluate to either 'true' of 'false'. Your 'Level' variable is not of type Boolean (neither 'true' nor 'false'), so you'll always be stuck with the default scenario.

Use the following notation

```
switch(Level) {

case "R":
   return 0;

default:
  return Level;

}
```

Btw, putting 'break' after 'return' is completely redundant.